# Logstash error: Rejecting mapping update to [db] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [meeting_invities, meetingroom "}}}}

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

```
Rejecting mapping update to [db] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [meeting_invities, meetingroom
"}}}}
```

below is my logstatsh-mysql.conf  I have to use multiple table in jdbc input. Please advise

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "pwd"

        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM meeting"
        tags => "dat_meeting"
    }
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "pwd"

        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM meeting_invities;"
        tags => "dat_meeting_invities"


    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
    if "dat_meeting" in [tags]{elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "meetingroomdb"

         document_type => "meeting"   
    }
    }

    if "dat_meeting_invities" in [tags]{elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "meetingroomdb"

         document_type => "meeting_invities"   
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your elasticsearch output uses the option `document_type` with two different values, this option sets the `_type` field of the index, since version 6.X you can only have one type in your index.

This option is deprecated in version 7.X and will be removed in future versions, since elasticsearch is going [typeless](https://www.elastic.co/blog/moving-from-types-to-typeless-apis-in-elasticsearch-7-0).

Since elasticsearch won't allow you to index more than one index type, You need to see what is the type of the first document you indexed, this is the type that elasticsearch will use for any future document, use this in both `document_type` option.